# conditional expectation deck of cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $X1, \ X2, \ X3, \ X4$ denote the number of hearts, diamonds, clubs, and spades drawn from 10 draws with replacement from a standard 52 card deck of playing cards.

What is $E\ [X2\ |\ X1 + X4 = 5]$  ?

Is the answer $1/4 * 5 = 5/4$ ? My reasoning is that we know that 5 of the 10 cards are not $X2$, so we are only concerned with the other 5. So we multiply the other 5 by the probability of getting a heart, i.e. $1/4$. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer $\dfrac14*5$ would be correct for $E[X2 | X1+X4 \geq 5]$. As would your reasoning. But $X1 + X4$ is exactly 5, no more.

Your reasoning starts out correctly: we know that 5 cards are not X2, so we can disregard them. This leaves us with 5 cards.

This is where you cut a crucial corner. We know that the remaining 5 cards are not X1 or X4, because X1 + X4 is already 5 from the first 5 cards. Another card in that camp would push the sum over 5. We know that the remaining 5 cards are not X1 or X4, so they must be X2 or X3 with equal probability: $\dfrac12$ for both.

Ultimately, the correct answer is $5*0 + 5*\dfrac12 = \dfrac52$

That's 5 cards that are X1 or X4 and 5 cards that are X2 or X3.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks so much. You're right, i totally disregarded the fact that the 5 remaining cards can be X3 OR X2. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathsf E(X_\diamondsuit\mid X_\heartsuit+X_\spadesuit=5)$ is the expected count for diamonds in 10 draws (with replacement) given that we know *exactly* five of the cards are either hearts or spades.

That is the expected count for diamonds among five cards that are each either diamonds or clubs, with equal likelyhood.

> $$\frac{5}{2}$$